# Can JavaScript set attributes like height, width?

Tags: php, jquery, html, slider

I have a image that is stored in my files.

I want to view this image in 3 different sizes. So I use `<img src>` tag and define different height & width 3 times.

It was working perfectly fine when I was just echoing it. Now I want to view this in a slider, and I have add JavaScript code in it.

Its working fine for 'Thumb image' because it has `<img src>` tag with it, but small image and large image doesn't have `<img src>` tag and I am unable to understand how to resize image in both `'smallimage:' &'largeimage:`'.

I don't know much about JavaScript. I just copied JavaScript code from somewhere else.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.jqzoom.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
            zoomType: 'innerzoom',
            preloadImages: false,
            alwaysOn:false
        });
    });
</script>


<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top" ><div class="clearfix" style="margin-left:-30px;">
        <a href="images/imgProd2/bracelets_Diamond.png" class="jqzoom" rel='gal1'  title="triumph" >         
            <img src='<?php echo $single_image_query_fetch['images']; ?>' height='261' width='325'  
                title='triumph'  style='border: 4px solid #666;'>            
        </a>
        </div>
        <br/>

      <!-------------------------------- Images Part is strating from here ------------------------->

        <div class="clearfix" style="margin-left:-30px; margin-top:-10px;" >
            <ul id="thumblist" class="clearfix" >

                $image_query = "select * from product_images where product_id=$id";
                $image_query_run = mysql_query($image_query);
                while( $image_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($image_query_run)) {

                    //Thumb                 
                    $thumb_image =
                        "<img src=http://localhost/cms/". 
                                $image_query_fetch['images'] ." height='80' width='100' alt=\"\" />";


                    //large
                    $big_image = "<img src=http://localhost/cms/". 
                            $image_query_fetch['images'] ." height='1024' width='1280' alt=\""/>";
                            $image_fetch[1]= $big_image;

                    //small                                 
                    $small_image = "<img src=http://localhost/cms/". 
                                    $image_query_fetch['images'] ." height='261' width='325' alt=\"\" />";
                <li>
                <a  href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', 
                                                        smallimage: 'images/imgProd2/Bracelet_Silver.png',
                                                        largeimage: 'images/imgProd2/bracelets_Diamond.png'}">
                        <img src='<?php echo $image_fetch[0]; ?>' height='80' width='100' >
                    </a>
            </li>
}
```

In `<li>` i want to define sizes for `smallimage` and `largeimage`. Kindly tell me how to do it.

Comment: So you copy-pasted the JS from somewhere else, and now you want SO to tailor it to your needs? Learn to write your own JS, or hire someone to do it for you. This isn't a free code-generator. (The answer to the title question _"Can JS set attributes"_ is: No, not JS, but the DOM can, and browser implementations of JS include the DOM API which offers the methods you need to do so)

Comment: If you have only **one** image size on your server, with CSS or JS you can only force the **browser** to **resize** the image, but not to physically make it smaller. Use some PHP image resizing library that will resize and store on your server different image sizes. Otherwise you could read an image in Canvas, and send different sizes to the server for storing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

**For height** :

```
$(".smallimage").height(100);
```

**For width** :

```
$(".smallimage").width(150);
```

Change 100 and 150 to your value or a dynamic one...

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so Much for the response! I know it sounds stupid, but can you please tell me where to add these lines.

Comment: Can you tell me from where you got the source code from ? If so maybe i can check that out and give a proper answer. Maybe the plugin itself has some settings you can tweak on.

Comment: I downloaded the j query  code from here 
http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/archives/jqzoom_ev-2.3.zip

Answer (score 1):

```
$("smallimage").css('height', 'num_here');
$("smallimage").css('width', 'num_here');

$("largeimage").css('height', 'num_here');
$("largeimage").css('width', 'num_here');
```

I don't know whether largeimage and smallimage or classes or id's so you'll have to specify that yourself assuming you know how to do that... because height and width property are shown in the jquery documentation. Not only that but this question must have been asked 100+ times on here.